# Preventing Empty Data from Inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that provides the user with an option to post within 1 of 3 columns. If the user decides they want to post in the first column, then they click the column 1 button and my jquery script removes the other 2 input fields.

The issue is that each one of these columns are linked to its own table within the database, so every time a user enters information into 1 of the columns, it's sent to the landing page where it updates all 3 tables.

If the user where to select Column 1, then their information will be inserted in to the Column 1 table, but blank rows will also be inserted into table 2 and 3.

```
<?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("URL", "DB", "password","DB_Name");
      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     // escape variables for security
     $Main= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_1']);
     $storyn1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn1']);

     $sql="INSERT INTO Column_1 (Link1, storyn1) 
     VALUES ('$Main', '$storyn1')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

   $con=mysqli_connect("URL", "DB", "password","DB_Name");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

     // escape variables for security
    $MLB= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['MLB']);
    $storyn2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn2']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO Column_2 (Link, storyn2) 
    VALUES ('$MLB', '$storyn2')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    $con=mysqli_connect("URL", "DB", "password","DB_Name");;
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

     // escape variables for security
     $Column_3= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_3']);
     $storyn3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn3']);

     $sql="INSERT INTO Column_3 (Link3, storyn3) 
     VALUES ('$Column_3', '$storyn3')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
     }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I feel like the reason I'm getting blank rows inserted into my table is because this page contains insert code for all 3 tables. Whats the best practice for this? Do I need to have 3 separate landing pages to house these insertion codes?

Here is the updated Code from the suggestions below:

```
                 // escape variables for security
                $Main= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_1']);
                $storyn1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn1']);

                $MLB= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['MLB']);
                $storyn2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn2']);

                $Column_3= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_3']);
                $storyn3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn3']);

                if(!empty($_POST['Column_1']) && !empty($_POST['storyn1'])) {
                          $sql="INSERT INTO Column_1 (Link1, storyn1) 
                     VALUES ('$Main', '$storyn1')";
                    }

                    if(!empty($_POST['MLB']) && !empty($_POST['storyn2'])) {
                       $sql="INSERT INTO Column_2 (Link, storyn2) 
                VALUES ('$MLB', '$storyn2')";
                    }

                  if(!empty($_POST['Link3']) && !empty($_POST['storyn3'])) {
                        $sql="INSERT INTO Column_3 (Link3, storyn3) 
                VALUES ('$Column_3', '$storyn3')";
                    }


                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the PHP [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) method to check if the user-submitted values are empty prior to performing the insert operation. So your codes may look like:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['Column_1']) && !empty($_POST['storyn1'])) {
        // insert into table Column_1
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['MLB']) && !empty($_POST['storyn2'])) {
        // insert into table Column_2
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['Link3']) && !empty($_POST['storyn3'])) {
        // insert into table Column_3
    }
?>
```

As for whether you need to have 3 separate landing pages (or forms, views etc.), it's not required; it really depends on whether your 3 columns form a cohesive, logical grouping. My suggestion is definitely to refactor your PHP codes to use [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Is there any reason I would be getting a `500 Internal Server Error` with this method? I entered this after the escape variables, and then entered the `Insert` for each one, and I'm getting this error

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Any error logs on the server? Try update the post with your new codes.

Comment: Fixed the error message, but now it's not saving anything to the database table. I'll update the post if you want to see the new code

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Aren't you supposed to include `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }`
in each `if` statement?

Comment: Just did, and still isn't adding to the database table. Feeling like such a NOOB right now lol.

Comment: Fixed it! it was a matter of the misnamed variable being placed in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

One change you could make that would involve minimal refactoring would be to simply check the user input after escaping it to see if it is empty, and then conditionally add it to the databases.  For example

```
// escape variables for security
$Main= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_1']);
$storyn1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn1']);

$MLB= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['MLB']);
$storyn2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn2'This]);

$Column_3= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Column_3']);
$storyn3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['storyn3'])

if(!(empty($Main) || empty($story1)) {
     $sql="INSERT INTO Column_1 (Link1, storyn1) 
     VALUES ('$Main', '$storyn1')";
}

elseif (!(empty($MLB) || empty($story2)){
... etc...
}
elseif (!(empty($Column_3) || empty($story3)){
...etc...
}
else{
... they are all empty !! ...
}
```

The way I did it with the if-else sequece has the potential added benefit of only ever adding to one of them.

Comment: Hmmm trying this method and I got a "500 internal Server Error" obviously I did something incorrect or am leaving something off.

Comment: Fixed the error message, but now it's not saving anything to the database table.

Comment: Hmm, this is really not enough info to go on.  IS it possible it is somehow getting to the situation where it thinks they are all blank?  Are your *if* statements correct?

Comment: I feel like I am. Your `if-else` statements were giving me a 500 error, so I tried @isim's example and it loaded the landing page successfully, but didn't actually save to the database.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's wrong with them, sorry about that.  Anyway, you still need to execute the sql with 

    `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Hmmm. Just added it to each if statement, and it's still not saving

Comment: Fixed it! it was a matter of the misnamed variable being placed in the if statement