# PHP/MySQL - Check Duplicate Data and Prevent to insert empty value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm Learning PHP MySQL. I write a HTML form to insert email and country name in the mysql datebase. I success. But there is some problem.. How I check duplicate data and prevent insert empty data?

here is my HTML code

```
<form action="add_entry.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateEmail();">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="email" required="required">
    <input type="text" name="country">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue"  onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Loading...';" disabled>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
 {
alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
return false;
 }
 }
  </script>
  <script>
    $("form > *").change(function() {
      var fields = $("form input").not("input[type='submit']");
      var filledFields = fields.filter(function() {
        return $(this).val().length > 0;
      });
      if (filledFields.length == fields.length) {
        $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Here is **add_entry.php** code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbusername","dbpassword");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO dbtablename (id,email, country) VALUES (null,'$_POST[email]','$_POST[country]')";
?>
<?php if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) : ?>
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
<?php else : ?>
    <center>Success!</center>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mywebsite.com/content.html" />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Now I don't understand I write both code in add_entry.php... check duplicate & prevent from inserting empty data code ..

I got both code in [Prevent duplicate data being entered into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081424/prevent-duplicate-data-being-entered-into-mysql-database) & [Preventing Empty Data from Inserting into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152290/preventing-empty-data-from-inserting-into-database) in StackOverFlow. I see there someone tell in "Prevent duplicate data code" was SQL Injectable ..

code is

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='".$email."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

        echo "email already exists";
    }else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO emails (email)    VALUES  ('".$_POST[email]."')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
```

Now Please help me, How can I solve this problem..

I want this, If some one try to insert empty data or try to directly access **add_entry.php** page, then he will automatically redirect to form page... and show a warning if possible "you must write your email to continue.."

If duplicate email found, then it will not insert database, he will automatically redirect to **content.html** page..

When successfully insert data, he will automatically redirect  **content.html** page..

---

***If an expert help me to write this code, it will be his greatness, I hope Someone must be help me to learn php/mysql practically. I also trying.. but I need your help to continue my study. I want to be an expert like you and want to help other.. Please help me to learn. Thanks a lot.***

Answer (score 1):

Try it this code will work

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbusername","dbpassword");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='".$email."'",$con);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbtablename (email, country) VALUES ('$email','$country')",$con)die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
echo "email already exists";
}
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions... but code give me a "unexpected T_EXIT" where die('Error: ' . mysql_error());